# Removing not visible rows from DataGridView

Tags: c#, windows, datagridview

My environment:
Windows 7 Ultimate, C#, VS2010 Ultimate, WinForm.

Target: Windows from XP to 7.

My application adds a data to a DataGridView row in 1 minute intervals.

My DataGridView has 15 rows and 8 columns.

In the 16th to add data; first the DataGridView will roll up, insert a blank row and then add the data in this new row, right?

My question: The rolled up row of DataGridView is still in memory?

If yes, how to remove this row of the DataGridView, keeping in DataGridView memory only the rows that are visibles?

Thanks in advance,
ocaccy

Comment: Always keep max 15 rows. If added 16th remove first (`datagridview.Rows[0].Remove()`)

Comment: Hi, I use this code to add a new row. 
private void tmr_GET_Tick(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
dataGridview1.Rows[0].Remove(); //Add this from your answer, OK?
string[] row= { ar[i, 0], ar[i, 1], ar[i, 2], ar[i, 3], ar[i, 4], ar[i, 5], ar[i, 6], ar[i, 7]};
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
 }

Comment: HI, which condition we should put to have already filled 15 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fastest solution keep maximum 15 rows in your datagridview:
This will work if your maximum rows quantity is constant

```
private void tmr_GET_Tick(object sender,EventArgs e) 
{
    //copied from your comment
    string[] row= { ar[i, 0], ar[i, 1], ar[i, 2], ar[i, 3], ar[i, 4], ar[i, 5], ar[i, 6], ar[i, 7]}; 
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row); 
    //Check if max rows quantity exceeds and remove first row
    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count = 16)
        dataGridview1.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
}
```